# Разделение html sitemap

Tags: php, wordpress, sitemap

Есть страница с html sitemap. На этой странице находится порядка 2000 ссылок. В какой способ можно их(список ссылок) разделить, чтобы на одной странице было не больше 100 ссылок. Вот примерно такое - https://www1.1movies.se/sitemap
Может подскажите плагины на вордпрессе для разбивки контента. Спасибо

Comment: я чего-то не знаю, или с каких это пор sitemap у нас не в xml?

Comment: @Manitikyl html карта - это для пользователей больше, чем для поисковых машин

Comment: это больше для пользователей? а что вы там собрались делать? ну кроме парсерства. sitemap - всю жизнь был для поисковиков.

Comment: А по вашему вопросу, не понятно как получилось 2000 ссылок, вы сами код написали или плагин используете? нужно больше инфы.

Comment: @Manitikyl Использовал плагин. Все 2000 ссылок - внутренние ссылки с сайта(страницы, страницы блога). Сайт создан на вордпрессе

Comment: Ну значит нужно крутить плагин, если он поддерживает разделение по "папочкам", то думаю там надо просто поменять значение. Если нет, то переписывать плагин, либо искать другой. :<

Comment: @Manitikyl С ссылками и их количеством все нормально. Мне просто хотелось бы разбить их на несколько подподкатегорий(
Секция 0 - ссылка 0 - ссылка 99, 
Секция 1 - ссылка 100 - 199 и тд). Надеюсь, понятно описал это

Comment: @Manitikyl в том то и дело, что штук 20 плагинов перепробовал и ни один такое не предлагает(максимум этих плагинов - включить и исключить страницы). Но все равно, спасибо за ответ !

Comment: 2000 ссылок для пользователей? Да ну на! Выкинуть нафик этот рудимент прошлого века!

Comment: @SeVlad я не владелец сайта, я всего лишь его обслуживаю